# What does <> "~" mean in SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, tilde

I have an SP and part of it states this:

```
    AND t_phlcm.VAT_FG  <>  "~"
```

Can you explain the <> "~" part? Does tilde (~) has a special meaning in SQL like % does?

Comment: No. Doesn't mean anything in SQL. Maybe tilde is just used by the application where `NULL` would be more appropriate.

Comment: No, is a simple string comparing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an example of simple string comparison which says 
`t_phlcm.VAT_FG must not be equal to "~" character.`

Although `~` can be used with regular expressions *in Postgres* like this :

`SELECT * FROM table where name ~ '^ABC'`

and is more powerful but is not advised as LIKE(~~) is more fast.
Please refer [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-matching.html)

Generally speaking `~` is used to complement an integer or bit like this:

`Update Users Set [Status] = ~[Status]`
will invert the status of all users.

Comment: You should explicitely mention that the `~` operator is Postgres specific. It is not a standard SQL operator.

Comment: Thanks. Which DBMS supports the `Status = ~Status` expression? Never seen that.

Answer (score 0):

All SQL server versions **after 2014** supports '~' operator, its bitwise not operator.
I use it mostly to **invert value of some flags (bit columns)** in my DB.
You can see more   [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-not-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).